# Integrability of supremum of continuous, integrable functions over compact space

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}_+$, such that $(\theta, x) \mapsto f(\theta, x)$ is continuous, and $x \mapsto f(\theta, x)$ is Lebesgue integrable for every $\theta \in \mathbf{R}^d$. Let now $\Theta \subseteq \mathbf{R}^d$ be compact. I am trying to prove that the supremum function $g(x) := \sup_{\theta \in \Theta} f(\theta, x)$ is Lebesgue integrable as well.

Anyone that can help? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does "continuous in both $\theta$ and $k$" mean "continuous in $\theta$ and continuous in $k$'. or "continuous in $(\theta,k)$"? (If the latter just saying "continuous" would have been better.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I meant the latter. You are right, I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample with $d=1$: Say $\phi:\Bbb R\to[0,\infty)$ is continuous with compact support, $\phi\ne0$. Let $$f(\theta,x)=\begin{cases}\phi\left(x-\frac1\theta\right),&\theta>0,
\\0,&\theta\le0,\end{cases}$$ $\Theta=[0,1]$.

Comment: This is indeed a counterexample. The problem I am looking at is a bit more specific (i.e. I have some more assumptions at my disposal), but I thought it would follow from this more general result. I am new to this platform, but I guess a whole new post is in place then? I will post a link to this new question shortly.

Comment: Here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800268/integrability-of-supremum-of-exponential-family-densities-over-compact-space